# IronPython Script Help - Export Cross Table to Excel in SPotfire

Tags: export-to-excel, ironpython, spotfire

I am new to IronPython and trying to use the below code to export my cross table from Spotfire to excel.

How do I modify this script to include defining the vizTable?

```
import System
from System.IO import FileStream, FileMode
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot
from  Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import SaveFileDialog  
SaveFile = SaveFileDialog()   #GETS THE FILE PATH FROM THE USER THROUGH A FILEDIALOG
SaveFile.Filter = "xls Format (*.xls)|*.xlsx|*.xls|*.xlsx"
SaveFile.ShowDialog()
saveFilename = SaveFile.FileName
print "saveFilename=", saveFilename
stream = FileStream(saveFilename, FileMode.Create) #Export Table data to the file
vizTable.As[exportWellHeader]().ExportData(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.ExcelXlsxDataWriter, stream)
stream.Dispose()
```

I keep getting the  below error. I have set a script parameter but do not know where to incorporate into the script.

Error messages:

> saveFilename= C:\Users\D565046\Desktop\test 3.xlsx
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "Spotfire.Dxp.Application.ScriptSupport", line unknown, in  ExecuteForDebugging
>   File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
>   NameError: name 'vizTable' is not defined
>
> Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.UnboundNameException: name 'vizTable' is not defined
>      at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.MissingName(SymbolId name)
>      at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LanguageContext.LookupName(CodeContext context, SymbolId name)
>      at $456##456(Closure , Scope , LanguageContext )
>      at   Spotfire.Dxp.Application.ScriptSupport.IronPythonScriptEngine.ExecuteForDebugging(String scriptCode, Dictionary`2 scope, Stream outputStream)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe two things are happening here.
1) `vizTable` should be defined in the "script parameters" area below the script, exactly as you have done with `exportWellHeader` and referencing the visualization (cross table) you want to export.
2) I believe line 14 is incorrect and you should not have something like `exportWellHeader`.  I think it should read more like:
`vizTable.As[CrossTablePlot]().ExportText(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.ExcelXlsxDataWriter, stream)`

Source: http://easyspotfire.blogspot.com/2014/11/export-cross-table-visualization-to-file.html

Please note that in the referenced link, the script author is exporting data to a text file, rather than an Excel file.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I am still getting the below error when I replaced the line it still gave me the below error. Any suggestions? SaveFilename= C:\Users\Desktop\rf.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Spotfire.Dxp.Application.ScriptSupport", line unknown, in ExecuteForDebugging
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
NameError: name 'vizTable' is not defined
Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.UnboundNameException: name 'vizTable' is

Comment: Hi, did you include 'vizTable' as script parameter?  The error seems to say that vizTable is not defined.  Would it be possible to update your post with a new screenshot?